# Populate a form field with page URL

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I have a downloads section on a client wordpress site. Using Download Monitor plugin. They are protected with a form using the Ninja Forms addon for the DM plugin so users have to register details to access the download.

I'd like to add the ID from the download form URL to a field in the form so client can see which download that form registration is associated with.

The generated url of the unlock registration form for a particular download is similar to the following:

https://domain.com/no-access/download-id/572/

I have found how to do this with a query string ( https://ninjaforms.com/how-to-auto-populate-form-fields-using-query-string/ )  but not sure how to do it with the IDs in my url above.

Ideally I'd like to translate that ID to the actual download title too if that's possible.

Can anyone please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the id is always at the end of the url that way, you can use [basename](http://php.net/basename) to grab it very simply:

```
<?php
    // in your code you will do this:
    //$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // but for this example, i need your url:
    $url = 'https://domain.com/no-access/download-id/572/';

    // grab the basename:
    $id = basename($url);

    echo "($id)"; // (572)
```

**ADDITION**

Now that you can find that `$id` which is the download-id requested, put it in a variable that you can use within the code that is writing your ninja form.  For instance:

```
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // this was just for debugging...now comment it out
    // $url = 'https://domain.com/no-access/download-id/572/';
    // echo "($id)"; (572)

    $id = basename($url);

    // instead put it in a variable you can use in your form
    $GLOBALS['requested-download-id'] = (integer) $id;
```

Now wherever you have the code for your ninja form do something like this:

```
<form id="ninja-form" action="your-action" method="POST">

  <?php
    // sanity check...something may have gone wrong
    if (empty($GLOBALS['requested-download-id'])) {
      $download_id = 'NOT FOUND';
    } else {
      $download_id = $GLOBALS['requested-download-id'];
    }
  ?>
  <input value="<?php echo $download_id; ?>" type="hidden" name="download-id">
```

**EVEN MORE SIMPLIFIED - DO IT ALL AT ONCE**

```
<form id="ninja-form" action="your-action" method="POST">

  <?php
    $id = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // be sure you ended up with a number
    $id = (integer) $id;

    if (empty($id)) {
      $download_id = 'NOT FOUND';
    } else {
      $download_id = $id;
    }
  ?>
  <input value="<?php echo $download_id; ?>" type="hidden" name="download-id">
```

Comment: Ok thanks so I would change url to https://domain.com/no-access/ then it would take 572 as the basename is that right? I now need to work out how to add this to a hidden field on the ninja forms form

Comment: Post some code pls.  Also, I am not following the comment on changing your url to no-access.  I simply copied your example url.  If you get the `basename()` of `domain.com/no-access` then you will be grabbing `no-access` instead of `572`.

Comment: see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166749/populate-a-form-field-with-page-url/#answer-41166873)

Comment: sorry if I'm not following this correctly and thanks for the ehlp, the ID will be different each time this page loads depending on the download file they clicked, when they click to download a file, the no-access page loads with the download ID and the registration form. The form is not hard coded, it's built thought he ninja forms plugin

Comment: In your code you will use `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` which pulls the download-id filled url.

Comment: Review carefully **ADDITION** as i have updated it to clarify that we are not *hardcoding* anything.  `REQUEST_URI`  = *something like* `/no-access/download-id/572/`.

Comment: awesome thanks, will have a go this evening and report back

Comment: Ok I added this onto the page template <?php
    $id = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // be sure you ended up with a number
    $id = (integer) $id;

    if (empty($id)) {
      $download_id = 'NOT FOUND';
    } else {
      $download_id = $id;
    }
  ?>

Comment: then in the ninja forms I add a hidden field and choose 'custom' as the type and <input value="<?php echo $download_id; ?>" type="hidden" name="download-id"> as the value. I suspect this is not the way to do it as nothing comes through at all for that field when form is submitted. Sorry I'm being lame, really unsure what I'm doing here!!